# Is it possible to use youtube analytics Api in that way?

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

Hi i create application that is common to youtube and i`ve got some questions. I use google login(oAuth), so i keep in my database all things required to use google APIs for every user that wants to log in. The question is if i can use(is it possible and legal) google analytics to get info(like gender of people which shows his/her video or age or region) about every user that is loged in to my application and show it to another users which using my application ?

edit: 
I do not know if you understood me well, user log in to my app with his google account, i have in my database his google token, etc. In my application all users have got youtube account and now what i want to do is that if you are log in, you can see user`s statistics from youtube(like the gender of people who watch his/her video and what is thier age) for any user registered in my app. There is a youtube analyse api, which alow you to get your account stats, and if i have access to someone`s google account(i keep toke in my datbase), i couldnt just use it to request that analyse api for every user and in that way get access to their stats. And another question is if i get data in the way that i described(of course if it is possibe), is it legall, if i can display such an info to other users not only to the owner of the account?
Thanks for help

Comment: Youtube analytics api is not the same as Google Analytics.    Youtube analytics is use to define analytics of a youtube video.   Google Analytics is for web page and mobile application analytics.   Please correct your tagging and the wording in your question.     It has nothing to do with Google Analytics api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it legall, if i can display such an info to other users not only to the owner of the account? Thanks for help

If you are authenticating a user to get access to their Private data.   It is your responsibility as a developer to ensure that their data remains private.  You should not be sharing data between your users without there express permission.

If the data you are accessing is public then you are allowed to display that data with anyone.

Remember when you created your google developer console account you agreed to this [Google APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/terms/#d_user_privacy_and_api_clients)

> b. Compliance with Law, Third Party Rights, and Other Google Terms of Service
>   You will comply with all applicable law, regulation, and third party rights (including without limitation laws regarding the import or export of data or software, privacy, and local laws). You will not use the APIs to encourage or promote illegal activity or violation of third party rights. You will not violate any other terms of service with Google (or its affiliates).

[d. User Privacy and API Clients](https://developers.google.com/terms/#d_user_privacy_and_api_clients)

> You will comply with all applicable privacy laws and regulations including those applying to PII. You will provide and adhere to a privacy policy for your API Client that clearly and accurately describes to users of your API Client what user information you collect and how you use and share such information (including for advertising) with Google and third parties.

You may also want to read [Privacy policy](https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/)